# jQuery help on method slideDown/slideUp can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, web, slidedown

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>YES</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        
        
        <img id="dramatic" src="statefair.jpg" width="400px" height="400px">
        <br>
        <button id="make_visible">HIDE</button>
        
        
        <style>
            img#dramatic {
            display: none;
            }
        </style>
        
        
        <script>
        
        $("button#make_visible").on("click", function() {
      $("img#dramatic").slideDown();
        });
        
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am working with a book and in the book I am learning jquery's slideDown/Up method. I ran the code originally on my main web page and it will not work. So I just created a simple YES.html(seen above) to make sure I was coding it correctly. However it will not slide up or down image. I don't know what I am missing for this to work. I am a beginner so I could be missing something simple. Please explain your answer/solution in steps if possible or maybe guide me to a web page tutorial of some sort. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?

```js
$('#make_visible').on('click', function (e) {
  /* method 1 */
  /*if ($('#dramatic').css('display') === 'none') {
    $('#dramatic').slideDown();
    $(this).html('Hide');
  }
  else {
    $('#dramatic').slideUp();
    $(this).html('show');
  }*/
  /* method 2 */
  $('#dramatic').slideToggle();
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML == 'HIDE' ? 'SHOW' : 'HIDE';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="make_visible">HIDE</button>
<br />
<img id="dramatic" src="statefair.jpg" width="400px" height="400px" />
```

Comment: Whoa thanks. That opens up a lot of ideas on how to use jquery based on that little code snippet.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't import jQuery, to use jQuery UI you have to import jQuery first.
Think this helps:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>YES</title>
            <script
                  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
                  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
                  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
        </head>

        <body>



            <img id="dramatic" src="statefair.jpg" width="400px" height="400px">
            <br>
            <button id="make_visible">HIDE</button>


            <style>
                img#dramatic {
                display: none;
                }
            </style>


            <script>

            $("button#make_visible").on("click", function() {
          $("img#dramatic").slideDown();
            });

            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also you should work on improving placement of your tags in HTML

Comment: Hey thanks. It worked. Yes I would love if you knew of any tutorials in where and how I should set up a html page with tags properly placed if you know of any?

Comment: w3schools is the best for beginning.

Comment: I would recommend KhanAcademy

Answer (score 0):

jQquery UI needs jQuery to function, so you should include that first. I used jQuery 1.3.2 as that seem to be the best fit for jQuery UI 1.8.

The book might be a bit dated as the latest version is 1.12.

I also changed the "onclick" code a bit:

```js
$( "button#make_visible" ).click(function() {
   $("img#dramatic").slideDown();
});
```

```css
        img#dramatic { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body>
<img id="dramatic" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Wisconsin_State_Fair.jpg" width="400px" height="400px">
    <br>
    <button id="make_visible">HIDE</button>

</body>
```